# Word VBA Add Inlineshape Object to Table Cell

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I'm creating a Word Document from MS Access VBA
I want to add an Inlineshape Object to a Table Cell:

I create the Foto Object like that:

```
Dim Foto As Inlineshape
Set Foto = WordObj.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:="C:\Test.jpg")
```

then I create my table to insert it.

```
Set tblNew = WordObj.Tables.Add(Range:=myRange, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=1, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitWindow)
```

How can I add the Foto object to a table cell?
I tried something like this

```
tblNew.Cell(1, 1).Range = Foto
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the table first, and then directly adding the *Foto* to that table by specifying the range on `.AddPicture`:

```
Set tblNew = WordObj.Tables.Add(Range:=myRange, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=1, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitWindow)
Dim Foto As Inlineshape
Set Foto = WordObj.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:="C:\Test.jpg", Range:=tblNew.Cell(1, 1).Range)
```